# alternative to SVG's flowRegion

Tags: javascript, html, browser, svg, wysiwyg

I would like to design an in-browser graphical (WYSIWYG) editor that can handle multiline text-boxes and column-like behaviour.

My first thought was to use SVG, which I can interact with it's DOM tree and manipulate it, finally exporting it's SVG code and using `<flowRoot>`,`<flowRegion>`,`<flowPara>` etc., then I came to understand that those features are part of SVG 1.2 specs and are not supported by browsers but only by few SVG renderers such as Inkscape, which drove me back to the drawing board.
(I modified the latest version of [svg-edit](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) to test-drive and then came to this conclusion)

At the back-end server level - I would like to be able to transform it to a PDF, which easily can be done with SVG, Postscript, PDF (duh) and maybe other formats.

HTML5's Canvas API is not an option because it's limited to raster images which will greatly reduce the content's quality.

What design approach would you recommend?

Comment: I'm doing the same thing - but browser support for SVG flowed text is poor afaik. So, all the rendering is done by Inkscape in the background - and then rendered to a low-res PNG for preview purposes. When the user is happy with the preview, they render to PDF. I'm using Gearman for a number of processing tasks, as I expect constant rendering to put a fair bit of load on the server!

Comment: Thanks, but it will hurt the usability of the application, won't it? I'm trying to achieve a plain & transparent WYSIWYG, as I mentioned. BTW, have you tried FPDF?

Comment: If you mean in performance, certainly browser-rendered SVG will put less load on the server. But I can render a low-res PNG in ~0.7sec, and a PDF in much the same time - and as I say much of my heavy duty stuff is pushed to a queue anyway. So, go for browser-side if you can, but I just don't think the support is there at the moment - and the pace of SVG standards development is glacial, so I won't be going browser-side for several years I should think!

Comment: FPDF - afaik that's a low-level PDF library, so not really useful for me. One can draw low-level primitives using that, and render the result to PDF, but I don't know if SVG can be imported, and even if it can, I'd be most surprised if it had the SVG text flow facility that Inkscape offers. Let me know if it does!